# Lim Sup inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Elementary Real Analysis, Thompson Bruckner & Bruckner.

For any sequence ${a_n}$, write $s_n = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n a_n$

Prove that $\limsup s_n \leq \limsup a_n$ and give an example that the inequality may be strict.

Here's my attempt: take $a_{2n} = 1, a_{2n-1} = 0.$ The inequality between them will be strict. For the former question, if $$\limsup a_n = L $$
then $$\exists\ l > L,\ \text{ and }\ N,\ \forall\ n\ge\ N, \ a_n < l  $$

So 
$$ \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} a_i + \frac1n\sum_{i=N}^n a_i \lt \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} a_i + \frac1n(n-N)l  $$
$$=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} a_i +(1-\frac{N}n)l\ \lt \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} a_i + l $$ 
I'm stuck here. Since l is arbtrarily close to L, will the inequality become 
$$ s_n \le \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} a_i + L\ ?$$
If I take the $\limsup$ of each side, the lip sum should be 0 + L on the right hand side. Does that conclude the proof?

Comment: There are some bugs in your trial in understanding the $\limsup$, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\limsup a_n = +\infty$, there is nothing to prove.

So we can assume $\limsup a_n = L < +\infty$. Then for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$, such that for all $n > N$, $a_n < L + \varepsilon$. For any $n_1 < n_2 < \cdots < n_k < \cdots$ such that $s_{n_k}$ converges as $k \to \infty$. If $n_k > N$,

$$s_{n_k} = \frac{1}{n_k}\sum_{i = 1}^{n_k}a_i = \frac{1}{n_k}\sum_{i = 1}^Na_i + \frac{1}{n_k} \sum_{i = N + 1}^{n_k} a_i < \frac{1}{n_k}\sum_{i = 1}^Na_i + \frac{n_k - N}{n_k}(L + \varepsilon)$$

Let $k \to \infty$, we have $$\lim_{k \to \infty} s_{n_k} \leq L + \varepsilon. \tag{1}$$
Since $s_{n_k}$ can be any convergent subsequence and $\limsup s_n$ is defined as the least upper bound of limits of convergent subsequences, $(1)$ implies $\limsup_{n \to \infty} s_n \leq L + \varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, the result follows.